# How to detect tap on cancel button with searchable modifier

Tags: ios15, searchable

I use the SwiftUI searchable of iOS15 modifier to make a search with the onSubmit modifier to send a HTTP request, and I also would like to reset the initial list when the user tap on Cancel button;
I would appreciated if I had found an onCancel modifier.
Is anyone that soled this?

Answer (score 10):

We have two environment values coming with .searchable, which are isSearching, and dismissSearch.

```
@Environment(\.isSearching) private var isSearching: Bool
@Environment(\.dismissSearch) private var dismissSearch
```

If we have our searchable code like the below

```
.searchable(text: self.$searchText)
```

Then we can detect the search being cancelled like the below snippet.

```
.onSubmit(of: .search) {
    //Search triggered on tap of search button in keyboard
}
.onChange(of: searchText) { value in
    if searchText.isEmpty && !isSearching {
        //Search cancelled here
    }
}
```

Try using this approach meanwhile apple hopefully comes up with some .onCancel(.search) modifier for us in the upcoming releases.

Comment: One important thing to note here is that `@Environment(\.isSearching) private var isSearching: Bool` only works on child views as per the documentation. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-search-interface-activation#Detect-search-activation